# How do I use the camera with media plugin on Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera, media

I'm working on an iOS/Android app in Xamarin Forms and one of the requirements is that users can use the camera to take photos. After a quick search, it appeared that James Montemagno's media plugin (xam.plugin.media) was the most used NuGet for this, so I decided on using it too. It seems to work just fine on iOS and on *some* Android devices. On other Android devices, the app becomes slow after taking two pictures and completely hangs and crashes after taking the third. This also happens if I re-take a picture without leaving the camera, both in debug and release configurations.

I have tested it on several devices:

```
Device         RAM      Crash?
Moto G4+       2 GB     Yes
OnePlus 5T     8 GB     Yes
Samsung J5     2 GB     No
```

I think this rules out a memory leak or excessive use of RAM (RAM usage also looks normal when debugging, but you never know...).

I double-checked, triple-checked *and* asked a colleague to make sure I followed all steps required to make it work, as described in the readme (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/README.md).

Searching on the internet has revealed nothing that looks relevant. Has anyone here experienced and/or fixed this, or have any information that I can use to find a solution?

Comment: Hi, by `re-take a picture without leaving the camera`, what do you mean?

Comment: When you take a picture, you are presented with a preview of the photo (I don't know if that's a standard Android thing or if that's a feature of the MediaPlugin library). There you have the option to accept the photo and dismiss the camera view or to delete the photo and take a new one without going back first.

Comment: Can you show me the crash messages? I have tested it on my phone, but it works well, and I haven't got too many mobiles. About the preview, it will show on my emulator, but not on my device.